# Multistep form href to a fieldset

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on multi step form, I am having trouble to add link. I want to add link inside progress bar so when I click progress bar 1 It will sent me to fieldset 1 if click number progress bar 3 it will sent met to fieldset number 3.

I gave fieldset an Id but when I added link inside progress bar it only worked for the first fieldset the others didn't work
`I put my code` [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/asgk372q/). Next and previous are working but I want add link inside progressbar so I can directly go to the step where I want to go.

**HTML:**

```
 <form id="msform">
  <!-- progressbar -->
  <ul id="progressbar">
    <a href="#1"><li class="active">Account Setup</li></a>
    <a href="#2"> <li>Social Profiles</li></a>
    <a href="#3"> <li>Personal Details</li></a>
  </ul>
  <!-- fieldsets -->
  <fieldset id="1">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Create your account</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">This is step 1</h3>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="Email"/>
    <input type="password" name="pass" placeholder="Password" />
    <input type="password" name="cpass" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="2">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Social Profiles</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">Your presence on the social network</h3>
    <input type="text" name="twitter" placeholder="Twitter" />
    <input type="text" name="facebook" placeholder="Facebook" />
    <input type="text" name="gplus" placeholder="Google Plus" />
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="button" name="next" class="next action-button" value="Next" />
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset id="3">
    <h2 class="fs-title">Personal Details</h2>
    <h3 class="fs-subtitle">We will never sell it</h3>
    <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First Name" />
    <input type="text" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" />
    <input type="text" name="phone" placeholder="Phone" />
    <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="previous" class="previous action-button" value="Previous" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit action-button" value="Submit" />
  </fieldset>
</form>
 <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js'></script>
```

Akkording html and css chat this an javascript issue.

Comment: I don't see jquery included in your code.

Comment: I am using cdnjs

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please edit your question, and add all relevant code-snippets to your question. Links go stale and we want stack overflow to be forever... (to help other people if they have the same problem as you)... also we don't like going to other sites to look at your code in order to help you solve your problem. please help us to help you.